# Windows 10 system process 25 % CPU

Tags: windows, cpu

ntoskrnl.exe!IoGetStackLimits+0x3060

when pc is idle for app 4 minutes, process starts taking app 25 % (one core) of CPU.

I have driver talent for update, I tried several windows 10 healing opetions.. but still remains. Malware scanned as well..

Comment: My suggestion is to stop using third-party software to update drivers.  Unless there is a problem a device driver should not be updated unless its a GPU.  If it is a GPU driver update just get it from AMD/Nvidia/Intel directly.

Comment: ok, I am downloading now Windows Driver Kit. I see there one issue in my Device list with Graphic card.. I dont know where to find driver..

Comment: What problem do you think the WDK is going to solve exactly?  If you are not specific we can't tell you where to find the driver for the device.

Comment: I just have seen articles about it.

Comment: Be specific what articles?

Comment: Problem is that the process ntoskrnl.exe!IoGetStackLimits+0x3060 starts all the time after few minutes to work and I dont know why. I see one problem in the graphic card driver so I was trying to solve it.

Comment: http://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/fix-high-ram-cpu-memory-usage-after-windows-10-update.html

Comment: That article has to do with memory usage on Windows 10 not high CPU usage.  Only the reported memory usage on Windows 10 is higher, because a change in the memory management, Windows 10 is actually more effective at the task then previous versions.

Comment: ok, I am not specialist.. do you have any possible solution, please?

Comment: I have asked very specific questions hoping you would provide the information require to provide you a solution.  That has not happened.

Comment: my card is GeForce GT 330M; laptop is Sony Vaio, Win10 is not supported by Sony for this model in drivers

Comment: If you know Windows 10 is not supported, and there are no graphic drivers for your device for that reason, you need to run your previous version of Windows.  WDK isn't going to solve this problem.  Your problem is connected to the fact you don't have the required chipset drivers installed which do not exist for your system since you are running Windows 10.

Comment: @David That article is 100% garbage. It suggests significant configuration changes that have a real impact on performance and system behavior in response to a purely cosmetic issue.

Comment: ok, I get it. For me one question, if there is anything else that could be done or can be the reason. I dont understand why if it should be driver, so it will behave like that. PC is working normally so why it should after few minutes start the process?

Answer (score 2):

capture a [xperf trace](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) of the CPU usage. First Install the WPT which is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk). Now open a cmd.exe as admin and run this command to capture 30s of the CPU usage:

> xperf -on latency -stackwalk profile -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 2048
>   -FileMode Circular && timeout 30 && xperf -d C:\HighCPUUsage.etl

Open the trace in [WPA.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh448171), [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh448137.aspx) from the [Microsoft symbol server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us).

Now Drag & drop the CPU usage (Sampled) graph to the right side of WPA and choice this layout and extand the stack of the SYSTEM Process and look where the CPU usage splits:

[image]
*(in this demo, the Kernel is busy zeroing the RAM).*

Now you should see the cause. If you need help, share the compressed ETL file so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: @David have you tried it? Do you see what causes the CPU usage?